# Format cells to percentage and restrict entering

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I want to format a cell as percentage with two decimals. I used format cell and keep the decimal places as 2.
But I want to restrict the full numbers to two.

```
Ex:23.45%
```

Then I used a custom format like

```
00.00%
```

But I couldn't restrict the entering more than two  numbers before decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this would be to use data validation. In the Data tab select data validation then in the settings tab set the type to decimal and restrict to between 0 and 1. If you then set the cell type to percentage then values will be represented in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, use:

- The percentage formatting for the final rendering
- The data validation for the input restriction

BUT: you need to set it up as user defined validation, with a formula like the following, considering `D2` is your reference cell:

```
=IF(D2=TRUNC(D2;2);TRUE;FALSE)
```